# Is it possible to preload pages without using iframes?

Tags: html

I have a list of links on a page. Some of the links are pretty slow. Is there a way to improve the loading speed on my end without preload/embed those sites into an iframe?

I've tried the link attribute `rel="preload"` to preload `document`s, but we'll have to embed them in iframes to render.

I hope none of my code will embed into the page once we redirected to the new URL.

Comment: No, because those pages need to be executed, not just "loaded", which will give you just the HTML, not the CSS, images or scripts. This sounds like a premature optimization issue. Probably a bad idea.

Comment: Let me be clear about this, I don't care the rendering speed in this case. The bottleneck here is the network loading speed. If there's only HTML DOMs rendered at the first time can be accepted. Or we can imagine the target links are pure HTML with texts, no css/javascript/images.

Comment: @eguitarz Is the new HTTP/2 Server Push technology an option?

Comment: You could grab the HTML via XHR but that really won't help you speed up subsequent page loads because the browser won't cache the content as if it were loaded as a page view.

Comment: @Progman Those outer links are not controlled by myself, so sadly it's not an option. I guess there's no good solutions at the moment. But thank you all for the inputs!